# How to COUNT duplicates in a DB and return them?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to ask for an advice on the best way for solving my problem.

I have a problem figuring out how to count duplicates in table like below

```
x       y  
1       a 
1       c
2       e 
2       g 
2       y
```

I would like to have number of duplicates and if possible to add info in extra columns such as:

result:

```
Row 1   Row 2   Row 3  Row 4 Row 5
1       a       c       -     2 
2       e       g       y     3
```

The problem is complex and there are a lot of other factors that need to be considered but I just need to understand this part as I don't really know where to start.

Any help as to what to search exactly for would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a known maximum amount of duplicates?  Is the count in Row 5 because you know there'll never be more than 3 values you want to output?

Comment: Your sample table doesn't have duplicate rows?

Comment: I don't know whether there will be or not more than 3 values I want to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat()` to bring all the values into a single column.  Perhaps this works for your purposes:

```
select x, group_concat(y), count(*)
from t
group by x;
```

Comment: This actually helps me with another part of my issue, but not the initial problem described above. Thank you so much for your input! Greatly appreciated, Gordon!

Comment: Actually, scratch that, I am stupid, things works perfectly for my original issue as well! Thank you so so much!